# nginx rewrite hierarchy to different files

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

This is Austin

I have this rewrite rules

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/? /state.php?state=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)? /city.php?state=$1&city=$2 last;
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that if the url includes only state
like mysite.com/california/
it should load state.php 
and if the url incldues state/city 
like mysite.com/california/san-diego/
it should load city.php

I tried switching the place of the rewrite rules but It doesn't rrquest the proper file.
Is there some type of conditional statement I can make with nginx rewrite to accomplish what I want?

Thank you.
Ps: I know I can do it if I add /state-california/ like so: ^/state-([^/]*)/?
but I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution which was putting $ in the end like

```
  rewrite ^/([^/]*)/**$**            /state.php?state=$1 last;
  rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/**$**    /city.php?state=$1&city=$2 last;
```